# Where can I find a calculator for constrained optimization of general form of algebraic equation?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, calculator

I'm working with a fairly complex equation and I need to carry out constrained optimization of the same. The first order differential equations are very messy to solve by hand and hence I thought to use online calculators. Problem with calculators like wolfram is that I cannot choose the variables with respect to which optimization needs to be done. If I use numbers in place of other variables it would defy the purpose. Are there any calculators available online for the problem I have? I am open to use coding based software like Matlab.

For example:
Maximize $\ ax^b - x$
w.r.t $\ x $
s.t. $\ x>0, a>1, 0<b<1 $
The original problem is multivariable and much more complex. I don't want to optimize with specific values for a,b.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you provide a concrete example of the problem you want to solve, the answers will be more accurate!